# NSPopover view controller - Communicate with parent via block or delegate?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, objective-c-blocks

Say I have a `NSViewController` which will be displayed in a popover using something similar to this:

```
- (void) createAndShowPopover
{
    TargetViewController * targetViewContoller = [[TargetViewController alloc] init];

    NSPopover * targetPopover = [[NSPopover alloc] init];
    targetPopover.contentViewController      = targetViewContoller;
    targetPopover.delegate                   = self;

    [targetPopover setAppearance: NSPopoverAppearanceMinimal];
    [targetPopover setAnimates: NO];
    [targetPopover setBehavior: NSPopoverBehaviorTransient];

    [targetPopover showRelativeToRect: ...];
}
```

Now `TargetViewContoller` contains a `NSTextView` and `NSButton`. When the button is clicked, I would like the parent controller (the view controller which owns `targetPopover`) to perform an action based on the contents of targetViews textView, then close the popover.

There are three ways I can think of doing this.

1. A block property on `targetViewController` such as `typedef void (^TextRestoreBlock) (NSString * textToRestore);` and adding the following code to the `createAndShowPopover` code:

   ```
   __unsafe_unretained typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
   targetController.restoreBlock =
   ^(NSString * textToRestore)
   {
       // Establish the strong self reference
       __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
   ```

   ```
   [strongSelf.textView setString: textToRestore];
   [strongSelf.targetPopover close];
   ```

   }; // Set our string
2. Using a delegate and instead having `createAndShowPopover` add:

   ```
   targetController.restoreDelegate = self;
   ```

And adding the code from the previous block to a delegate method.

I think I much prefer method #2 (delegate) as it seems neater. My overall question would be, is there a preferred style? Have I missed the mark completely?

Note that in my specific case, this is for mac development, but I believe the same concept would apply to iOS and `uipopovercontroller`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree method #2 has always worked for me. Although there aren't any overwhelming computational benefits to doing one or the other. #2 is cleaner and a bit easier to edit if you decide to add more functionality. Go for it.